# (bxslider) Using the slider pager with words instead of circles

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, bxslider, jquery-ui-slider

Is there a way to replace the circles in a pager for a slider with a word that represents each slide (like a clickable menu that slides the content below it)? The options are here http://bxslider.com/options but not sure which one could accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [buildPager](https://bxslider.com/options/#buildPager):

> If supplied, function is called on every slide element, and the
> returned value is used as the pager item markup.

Example page is here: [http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-2](https://web.archive.org/web/20171006193511/http://bxslider.com:80/examples/thumbnail-pager-2)

Your code would look something like this:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  buildPager: function(slideIndex){
    switch(slideIndex){
      case 0:
        return '<div>First slide</div>';
      case 1:
        return '<div>Secoond slide</div>';
      case 2:
        return '<div>Third slide</div>';
    }
  }
});
```